# Can you "dynamically bind" overloaded methods?

Tags: java, type-erasure, dynamic-binding, constructor-overloading, static-binding

```
public class ConstructorOverloading {
    static class A{
        final String msg;
        public A(Object o){
            this.msg = "via object";
        }

        public A(Integer i){
            this.msg = "via integer";
        }
    }

    public A aWith(Object o){return new A(o);}
    public A aWith(Integer i){return new A(i); }


    static class B{
        final String msg;
        public B(Object o){
            this.msg = "via object";
        }

        public B(Integer i){
            this.msg = "via integer";
        }
    }

    public <T> B bWith(T it){return new B(it);}

    public void test(){
        A aO = aWith(new Object());
        A aI = aWith(Integer.valueOf(14));

        B bO = bWith(new Object());
        B bI = bWith(Integer.valueOf(14));

        System.out.println(format("a0 -> %s", aO.msg));
        System.out.println(format("aI -> %s", aI.msg));
        System.out.println(format("b0 -> %s", bO.msg));
        System.out.println(format("bI -> %s", bI.msg));
    }
}
```

gives us

```
a0 -> via object
aI -> via integer
b0 -> via object
bI -> via object
```

I suppose that would be due to type erasure.

Can I do anything about this without having to insert explicit type checks or overloading `bWith`?

I mean, the app *knows* at runtime that it's supposed to call the constructor with an `Integer`-type argument, it just doesn't know to call the *right* constructor, after all...

Also -- since I am guessing the answer to be 'no' -- what would be the issue with allowing something like this?

Comment: "Can I do anything about this" What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: See the first answer of the linked duplicate: "In Java, dynamic method dispatch happens only for the object the method is called on, not for the parameter types of overloaded methods."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean, the app knows at runtime that it's supposed to call the constructor with an Integer-type argument, it just doesn't know to call the right constructor, after all...

No, it doesn't.

This method:

```
public <T> B bWith(T it){return new B(it);}
```

has to be able to work for any parameter: the compiler has to select a single constructor to invoke in that method. The only constructor which meets that criterion there is the `Object` one.

The only way you can make it do differently at runtime is with explicit casting (you may as well drop the type parameter, it is redundant):

```
public B bWith(Object it){
  if (it == null || it instanceof Integer) {
    return new B((Integer) it);
  }
  return new B(it);
}
```

Edit: added the `it == null` check, since `new B(null)` would actually invoke the `Integer` constructor, as it is the more specific of the two.